# Rails Warden before_logout is called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, warden

I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my call to Warden::Manager.before_logout was throwing a NoMethodError for NilClass when I tried to call 'user.my_method'.  Then I added a debug puts call to the before_logout block and discovered that it was being called TWICE on each logout - the first time with the user being nil, and then immediately after, with the user object supplied.  So I was able to inelegantly get around the exception by changing the call to 'user.my_method if user', but I'm still not comfortable with not knowing why before_logout is getting called twice.  Has anyone else seen this?  Is it perhaps one of those happens-in-development-only environment anomalies?

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
    user.update_attributes(is_active: true)
  end
  Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
    user.update_attributes(is_active: false) if user
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but you probably have two models (scopes in Warden's case): one for User and another for AdminUser. You can use an if statement for just the model/scope you want:

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
    if opts[:scope] == :user
       user.current_sign_in_at = nil
       user.save!
    end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

solve it by adding this in the config/initializers/devise.rb. Add code for what ever you want to do on logout.

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
  # store what ever you want on logout
  # If not in initializer it will generate two records (strange)
end
```

Comment: But that's where I have it, which is why it's so confusing.  Here's the first few lines of the config file:Devise.setup do |config|
  Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
    user.update_attributes(is_active: true)
  end
  Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
    user.update_attributes(is_active: false) if user
  end